# Good examples of (families of) tamely ramified extensions?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I am looking for examples of families of tamely ramified extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Thanks.

Comment: This can be useful for some readers: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293789/definition-of-tamely-ramified

Comment: What does tame ramification mean in the context of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @rondo: I fear none (assuming of course the possibility of being wrong)

Comment: I had been taking the following as my definition: If $p$ is a prime in $Z$, then the extension is tamely ramified above $(p)$ if the ramification index of any prime above $(p)$ is relatively prime to $p$. Is this not a standard definition? It is essentially the same as the first one in the link you provided. @LuisGomezSanchez

Comment: Fixing an integer $n$, if $f(x)$ is a monic degree $n$ polynomial which is separable (no common factors) modulo $p$ for all primes $p \le n$, then the corresponding extension given by a root of $f(x)$ (or the splitting field) will be tamely ramified everywhere, because it will be unramified at $p \le n$ by construction, and will be tamely ramified at $p > n$ because $p \nmid n!$. For example, if $n = 2$, then any quadratic congruent to $x^2+x+1$ modulo $2$ will work, and if $n  = 3$, then any cubic congruent to $x^3+x+1$ modulo $6$ will work.

Comment: Another type of example: the cyclotomic fields $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_N)$ for squarefree $N$.